# Retry skipped on new execution

Tags: spring-batch

In spring-batch, when processing a chunk based step, if data is corrupted or if my program bugs and can't be processed, default behaviour is that the job fails. If I correct that data/program and try to restart the job with the same parameters, step will restart from where it was at the start of the failed chunk.

If I don't want my step to stop when trying to process data, I can configure my step with skip :

```java
@Bean
public Step myStep(ItemReader<Person> reader, 
                   ItemProcessor<Person, Person> processor, 
                   ItemWriter<Person> writer){

   return stepBuilderFactory.get("my-step-name")
                            .<Person, Person>chunk(10)
                            .reader(reader)
                            .processor(processor)
                            .writer(writer)
                            .faultTolerant()
                            .skipLimit(MAX_SKIPS)
                            .skip(SkippableException.class)
                            .stream(reader)
                            .build();
}
```

The problem is now that the step (and job) is shown as complete and I can't restart it to complete the skipped items.

Is there a way I can achieve this ? How ?

Comment: Have you tried to set `.allowStartIfComplete(true)` on the step? Are you getting a `JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException` when you try to restart the job?

Comment: Both with and without `.allowStartIfComplete(true)`, I get this error : Failed to execute CommandLineRunner Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete

Comment: Kind of : I see this is not built-in spring batch and will have to find a workaround. writing unprocessed objects to a file won't be as easy as to write an xml thought.